# HmacSHA1 value is different from the java code

Tags: apex

I am trying to generate the HMAC SHA1 key using few parameters in Apex, but seems the output is different from that of the java code

My Apex Code:

```
String privateKey = 'bc30540b248aa5eb717c133ae3038222113f2a77';
String input = 'proxy_userowner@company.com.autimestamp2014-05-01T23:55:34Z';
Blob Signature = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.ValueOf(input), Blob.ValueOf(privateKey));
System.debug('Final sign ='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(Signature), 'UTF-8'));
```

Java code:

```
    String key = "bc30540b248aa5eb717c133ae3038222113f2a77";
    String data = "proxy_userowner@company.com.autimestamp2014-05-01T23:55:34Z";
    byte[] decodedKey = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "HmacSHA1");
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(keySpec);
    byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] signatureBytes = mac.doFinal(dataBytes);
    String signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signatureBytes), "UTF-8");
    String signatureParam = URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("signatureParam = " + signatureParam);
```

Output from the Apex code is

```
Final sign = m491puKdMNVcbmlQgUhe547853w%3D
```

Output from the Java code is

```
signatureParam = GeJ38GfvibEuH%2B84VZeANAy75kU%3D
```

Not sure what I am missing in the Apex code? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92589/why-doesnt-hmacsha1-generate-the-same-hash-as-my-c-code/92603#92603

Comment: Hi @Shi I followed the steps which was mentioned in the article you mentioned and I am not decoding my the key in my case. Even then I am not getting the same results. Therefore I posted this question.

Comment: Okay, to clarify. The -1 is not coming from me. I am not sure where is it coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Java code, you are unencoding the private key from hex, but you are not doing that in Apex. So, you need to modify your code to the following:

```
Blob privateKey = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex('bc30540b248aa5eb717c133ae3038222113f2a77');
String input = 'proxy_userowner@company.com.autimestamp2014-05-01T23:55:34Z';
Blob Signature = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.ValueOf(input), privateKey);
System.debug('Final sign ='+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64encode(Signature), 'UTF-8'));
```

That does give the same result as your Java